# Parsing nested JSON in spark and imposing custom schema

Tags: json, apache-spark, schema

I have a single line nested JSON in below format

```
{"2018-10-09": {"CAD": 1.4861, "JPY": 129.45, "NZD": 1.7784, "USD": 1.1435}, "2018-11-30": {"CAD": 1.5116, "JPY": 128.99, "NZD": 1.6556, "USD": 1.1359}}
```

This is just a part of the JSON,actual JSON is really big.

I need to read this JSON using spark and do some preprocessing.

Here is the code

```
df = spark.read.format("json") \
  .option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .option("header", 'false') \
  .option("sep", ",") \
  .load(file_location)

display(df)
```

[image]

The schema looks like below

[image]

I want the data to look like something like this

```
date        CAD   JPY     NZD   USD

2018-01-02  1.51  135.35  1.69  1.2

2018-01-03  1.50  134.97  1.69  1.209
```

so my new schema should contain 5 fields.

i tried to achieve it like below

```
df1=df.select("2018-12-27.CAD","2018-12-27.JPY","2018-12-27.NZD","2018-12-27.USD")
```

but it involves selecting each of the date value and there are 100s of date values.This is painful and time consuming.

what is the efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is in `scala`, May be you can convert this to `python`.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|2018-10-09                      |2018-11-30                      |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|[1.4861, 129.45, 1.7784, 1.1435]|[1.5116, 128.99, 1.6556, 1.1359]|
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

```
scala> val columns = df.columns
```

```
scala> 
val colExp = 
array(
    columns
    .map(c => 
        List(
            lit(c).as("date"),
            col(s"${c}.*")
        )
    )
    .map(l => struct(l:_*)):_*
)
```

```
scala> df.select(explode(colExp).as("data")).select("data.*").show(false)
+----------+------+------+------+------+
|date      |CAD   |JPY   |NZD   |USD   |
+----------+------+------+------+------+
|2018-10-09|1.4861|129.45|1.7784|1.1435|
|2018-11-30|1.5116|128.99|1.6556|1.1359|
+----------+------+------+------+------+
```

**Explanation**

```
val colExp = 
array(
    columns
    .map(c => List(lit(c).as("date"),col(s"${c}.*"))) // This one will create `2018-10-09` as `date`, `2018-10-09.*`
    .map(l => struct(l:_*)):_* // This will add above columns inside struct(_)
)
```

Above code will give you below output.

```
array(
    struct(
        lit("2018-10-09").as(`date`), 
        col("2018-10-09.*")
    ), 
    struct(
        lit("2018-11-30").as(`date`), 
        col("2018-11-30.*")
    )
)
```

Once you have above output, It is easy you just have to `explode` array & extract `struct` columns.

Comment: Can you elaborate it plz,what you did to achieve colExp?